# Why doesn't ||= work with arrays?

Tags: arrays, perl, operators

I use the `||=` operator to provide default values for variables, like

```
$x ||= 1;
```

I tried to use this syntax with an array but got a syntax error:

```
@array||= 1..3; 
Can't modify array dereference in logical or assignment (||=) ...
```

What does it mean and how should I provide arrays with default values?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Because `||` is a scalar operator.  If `@array||= 1..3;` worked, it would evaluate `1..3` in scalar context, which is not what you want.  It's also evaluating the array in scalar context (which is ok, because an empty array in scalar context is false), except that you can't assign to `scalar(@array)`.

To assign a default value, use:

```
@array = 1..3 unless @array;
```

But note that there's no way to tell the difference between an array that has never been initialized and one that has been assigned the empty list.  It's not like a scalar, where you can distinguish between `undef` and the empty string (although `||=` doesn't distinguish between them).

eugene y found [this perl.perl5.porters message](http://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.perl5.porters/2002/03/msg53441.html) (the official Perl developers' mailing list) that goes into more detail about this.

Comment: `||` is not a scalar operator although it does impose scalar context on it's left operand. From perlop: "Scalar or list context propagates down to the right operand if it is evaluated." `perl -MData::Dump=dump -e "@a = 0 || (1 .. 3); dump(\@a)"` prints `[1, 2, 3]`

Comment: *"there's no way to tell the difference between an array that has never been initialized and one that has been assigned the empty list"* It's not just impossible to tell the difference: *there is no difference*.

Comment: This answer is completely wrong. `perl -le'print 0 || 1..3'` prints `123`, not an empty line like `print scalar(1..3)` would print.

Answer (score 16):

This [page](http://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.perl5.porters/2002/03/msg53441.html) has a good explanation, imho:

> op= can occur between any two
>   expressions, not just a var and an
>   expression, *but* the left one must be
>   an lvalue in scalar context.
>
> Since `@x ||= 42` is equivalent to
>   `scalar(@x) = @x || 42`, and you aren't
>   allowed to use `scalar(@x)` as an
>   lvalue, you get an error.