# What's wrong with writing "@ARGV ||= '.';"?

Tags: perl

Why does Perl throw a fit at the following snippet?

```
$ perl -Mstrict -wE '@ARGV ||= ".";'
Can't modify array dereference in logical or assignment (||=) at -e line 1, near "'.';"
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.
```

While it happily processes

```
$ perl -Mstrict -wE '@ARGV = @ARGV || ".";'
```

---

I don't see the [`perldiag`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldiag.html) explanation helping here much:

> **Can't modify %s in %s**
>
> (F) You aren't allowed to assign to the item indicated, or otherwise
>   try to change it, such as with an auto-increment.

---

A more human-friendly explanation for this behavior is much appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4385998/why-doesnt-work-with-arrays

Comment: @mpapec : Thanks for finding the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's impossible for the code `@ARGV` to both return the array itself and the number of elements in it, so `@ARGV ||= '.';` makes no sense. You need to evaluate `@ARGV` twice, once in scalar context (to get the number of elements), and once as an lvalue (to get the array itself).

```
 @ARGV = @ARGV || '.';
```

Comment: Excellent answer that makes the issue crystal-clear. Thanks ikegami