# How do I use a default array if no command line arguments are given?

Tags: arrays, perl, default

The below appears to work correctly if no command line arguments are given, but when they are all I get is the number of arguments supplied, not the arguments themselves.  It appears `@ARGV` is being forced scalar by `||`.  I've also tried using `or` and `//` with similar results.  What is the correct operator to use here?

```
say for @ARGV || qw/one two three/;
```

Comment: There is no single operator to use in place of `||` that would make that work as desired.  The closest I can think of is `(@ARGV ? @ARGV : qw(one two))`

Comment: [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16883923/133939)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`||` operator](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Logical-or-and-Exclusive-Or) imposes the scalar context by the nature of what it does

> Binary `"or"` returns the **logical** disjunction of the two surrounding expressions. It's equivalent to `||` except for the very low precedence.

(emphasis mine). Thus when its left-hand-side operand is an array it gets the array's length.

However, if that's `0` then the right hand side is just evaluated

> This means that it short-circuits: the right expression is evaluated only if the left expression is false.

what is spelled out in [C-Style Logical Or in perlop](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#C-style-Logical-Or)

> Scalar or list context propagates down to the right operand if it is evaluated.

so you get the list in that case.

There is no operator that can perform what your statement desires. The closest may be

```
say for (@ARGV ? @ARGV : qw(one two));
```

but there are better and more systemic ways to deal with `@ARGV`.

Comment: `@ARGV = @ARGV || qw( one two three );`

Comment: @Zaid `perl -wE'@ary = qw(one two); say for (@ary = @ary || 1..3)'` prints `2 3`

Comment: Oh, I forgot to add the usage line: `say for @ARGV;`

Comment: @Zaid  Meets a similar fate, per Сухой27 link.  But this is fun:  `perl -wE'@ary = qw(a b); @ary = @ary || 1..3; say for @ary'` prints `2 3` while `perl -wE'@ary = qw(a b); @ary = @ary || qw(1 2 3); say for @ary'` prints `2`.

Answer (score 0):

Just write it as two lines.

```
@ARGV = qw[...] unless @ARGV;
say for @ARGV;
```